# how can can I speed up new.forward() process in OpenCV having CUDA?

Tags: python, opencv

How can can I speed up `new.forward()` process in OpenCV in Python having CUDA?

when I write

```
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_OPENCL)
```

I'm getting speed twice as slow
And show up next message as output:

```
OpenCV(ocl4dnn): consider to specify kernel configuration cache directory 
                 via OPENCV_OCL4DNN_CONFIG_PATH parameter.
OpenCL program build log: dnn/dummy
Status -11: CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE
-cl-no-subgroup-ifp
Error in processing command line: Don't understand command line argument "-cl-no-subgroup-ifp"!
```

I've got GeForce GTX 1050 and Cuda 10

Comment: Windows or Linux? It need to set "OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE=NVIDIA:GPU:"
Here: https://answers.opencv.org/question/147932/how-to-change-opencl-device/

Comment: @Nuzhny, Linux, what kind of setting is this? In linux environment or what?

Comment: Try this code: https://answers.opencv.org/question/62635/opencv-30-how-to-determine-which-gpu-is-used-for-opencl/?answer=64258#post-id-64258

Comment: CUDA support for OpenCV DNN module was [added](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/14827) just a week ago.